# System drive takes more space

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10

I have 185 GB System Drive Where Windows 10 is installed, now I tried to select all the folders and also the hidden folders then clicking on their properties. Now it show a size of 44.8 GB and a size on disk of 45.3 GB, but my problem is when I show the properties of the drive itself (with the Hard Disk logo) it shows a used space of 92.6 GB !
Is it Normal or something weird behind in it ?

Comment: This is normal, there are many SYSTEM folders that won't immediately give up their properties to a non-Administrator request.

Comment: were you able to see where you "waste" a lot of storage on the system drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting all files and showing properties skips files where your user accound doesn't have **access to** while showing the disk pproperties reads the NTFS meta data and always shows the correct usage.

Run [TreesizeFree](http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/) ([as admin](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/How-do-I-run-an-application-once-with-a-full-administrator-access-token)) to see a better view of the disk space usage.

[image]

[image]